# Golang regexp to match multiple patterns between keyword pairs

Tags: regex, go

I have a string which has two keywords: "CURRENT NAME(S)" and "NEW NAME(S)" and each of these keywords are followed by a bunch of words. I want to extract those set of words beyond each of these keywords. To elaborate with a code:

```
    s := `"CURRENT NAME(S)
 Name1, Name2",,"NEW NAME(S)
NewName1,NewName2"`
    re := regexp.MustCompile(`"CURRENT NAME(S).*",,"NEW NAME(S).*"`)

    segs := re.FindAllString(s, -1)
    fmt.Println("segs:", segs)

    segs2 := re.FindAllStringSubmatch(s, -1)
    fmt.Println("segs2:", segs2)
```

As you can see, the string 's' has the input. "Name1,Name2" is the current names list and "NewName1, NewName2" is the new names list. I want to extract these two lists. The two lists are separated by a comma. Each of the keywords are beginning with a double quote and their reach ends, when their corresponding double quote ends.

What is the way to use regexp such that the program can print "`Name1, Name2`" and "`NewName1,NewName2`" ?

Comment: Check [this demo](https://play.golang.org/p/BuU54evLzJ), does it look like what you are looking for?

Comment: Yes, it does. Thanks. you should have made it as an answer, instead of a comment.

Comment: Yes, I understood that now :) Thanks a lot.

Comment: the strings in your example are separated with two commas (before "NEW NAME(S) ), is it a typo?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue with your regex is that the input string contains newline symbols, and `.` in Go regex does not match a newline. Another issue is that the `.*` is a greedy pattern and will match as many symbols as it can up to the *last* second keyword. Also, you need to escape parentheses in the regex pattern to match the `(` and `)` literal symbols.

The best way to solve the issue is to change `.*` into a negated character class pattern `[^"]*` and place it inside a pair of non-escaped `(` and `)` to form a *capturing group* (a construct to get *submatches* from the match).

Here is a [Go demo](https://play.golang.org/p/UIkrCHCSpE):

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "regexp"
)

func main() {
    s := `"CURRENT NAME(S)
 Name1, Name2",,"NEW NAME(S)
NewName1,NewName2"`
    re := regexp.MustCompile(`"CURRENT NAME\(S\)\s*([^"]*)",,"NEW NAME\(S\)\s*([^"]*)"`)

    segs2 := re.FindAllStringSubmatch(s,-1)
    fmt.Printf("segs2: [%s; %s]", segs2[0][1], segs2[0][2])
}
```

Now, the regex matches:

- `"CURRENT NAME\(S\)` - a literal string "CURRENT NAME(S)`
- `\s*` - zero or more whitespaces
- `([^"]*)` - Group 1 capturing 0+ chars other than `"`
- `",,"NEW NAME\(S\)` - a literal string `",,"NEW NAME(S)`
- `\s*` - zero or more whitespaces
- `([^"]*)` - Group 2 capturing 0+ chars other than `"`
- `"`  - a literal `"`

Answer (score 1):

If your input doesn't change then the simplest way would be to use submatches (groups). You can try something like this:

```
// (?s) is a flag that enables '.' to match newlines
var r = regexp.MustCompile(`(?s)CURRENT NAME\(S\)(.*)",,"NEW NAME\(S\)(.*)"`)
fmt.Println(r.MatchString(s))
m := r.FindSubmatch([]byte(s)) // FindSubmatch requires []byte

for _, match := range m {
    s := string(match)
    fmt.Printf("Match - %d: %s\n", i, strings.Trim(s, "\n")) //remove the newline
}
```

Output: (Note that the first match is the entire input string because it completely matches the regex (https://golang.org/pkg/regexp/#Regexp.FindSubmatch)

```
Match - 0: CURRENT NAME(S)
Name1, Name2",,"NEW NAME(S)
NewName1,NewName2"
Match - 1: Name1, Name2
Match - 2: NewName1,NewName2
```

Example: https://play.golang.org/p/0cgBOMumtp

Comment: There is also a FindStringSubmatch that takes a string and returns a slice of strings.

Comment: This won't work if there are 2 or more pairs of keywords in the input string.

Answer (score 0):

For a fixed format like in the example, you can also avoid regular expressions and perform explicit parsing as in this example - https://play.golang.org/p/QDIyYiWJHt:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "strings"
)

func main() {
    s := `"CURRENT NAME(S)
 Name1, Name2",,"NEW NAME(S)
NewName1,NewName2"`

    names := []string{}
    parts := strings.Split(s, ",,")
    for _, part := range parts {
        part = strings.Trim(part, `"`)
        part = strings.TrimPrefix(part, "CURRENT NAME(S)")
        part = strings.TrimPrefix(part, "NEW NAME(S)")
        part = strings.TrimSpace(part)
        names = append(names, part)
    }
    fmt.Println("Names:")
    for _, name := range names {
        fmt.Println(name)
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Names:
Name1, Name2
NewName1,NewName2
```

It uses a few more lines of code but may make it easier to understand the processing logic at a first glance.